# Symfony get form model object

Tags: forms, symfony1, model

In my symfony application I would like to get form model object before calling save method.For example: on form submit I bind it to the related Form Object. And before calling save method I want to get related Model object with its submitted values.I know there is `$this->form->getObject()` method.When I call it before `$this->form->save();` method it returns model without values. Is there any way to get it? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form's values are only set in the object in save(). You have two options:

1. if the values are enough, use `$form->getValues()`, it returns the cleaned array
2. if they aren't, call [`$form->updateObject()`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/form/addon/sfFormObject.class.php#L174) manually.

Comment: thanks I tried your second suggestion and it works: ) first  i call $form->updateObject() method manually it returns object.this object is not persisted in database. And that is what i want...Thank you!!!